# How to retrieve JSON from request body using WebTau?

Tags: json, rest, testing, webtau

- I have sent a request to a REST servlet and it returns a JSON array

  - I need to get the JSON as a String for further processing.
- Originally I used this to get the body:

  ```
  DataNode  result =  body.get("carList");`
  return result.toString();`
  ```
- Then tried to parse the body, which is originally JSON, but ...
- This string threw an exception from the `Jackson` library:

  ```
  "Unexpected character ('c' (code 99)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
    at [Source: (String)"[{carNumber: 22248002, trailerNumber: }]"; line: 1, column: 4]"
  ```

  - These are the expected values.
  - They are not in a recognised JSON form.
- For the example above the requirement is: `[ {"carNumber" : "1234", "trailerNumber" : "567"}, ...  ]`

  - *See*: [JSON.org](https://www.json.org/)
- I have not (yet) found an example or guide  rooting about in the documentation.

  - I looked for things like `getJson()`, `getRaw()` and such.  I'm convinved it must be there.
  - In this case I want the entries from the list to use for testing an update operation.

Looking forward to your response.

Comment: I have deleted a post I added initially.   Turns-out that the apporach used gives me meta-data not the JSON payload string.  Just leaving this comment to document that action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

author of [WebTau](https://github.com/testingisdocumenting/webtau) here, thank you for using it.

To get the `DataNode` underlying value, return the node from the validation block. If the node represented object, than an instance of `Map` will be returned. `List` for JSON array and correspondent type like `String`, `Boolean` for simple values

```
Map<String, ?> bodyAsMap = http.get("/end-point", ((header, body) -> {
    return body;
}));
```

Note that it is not JSON yet. At this point you can convert Map back to JSON using any standard libraries. Or use WebTau `JsonUtils.serialize`.

Also worth noting that it is not the original response from the server, but rather parsed to DataNode, then to Map and then to String.

If you need to validate that JSON confirms to a schema you can use it directly [inside the validation block](https://testingisdocumenting.org/webtau/HTTP/JSON-schema/)

If you need original raw content, you can use undocumented `http` method

```
public HttpResponse getToFullUrl(String fullUrl, HttpHeader requestHeader)
```

object it returns has `getTextContent()` method to access originally received content.

Could you please elaborate why do you need raw content access? If there is a useful pattern, it may be a good idea to enable it in WebTau natively.

Comment: Things I like ... Raw response data is accessible, when one is testing I believe tou need to check the authentic data or frame not a reconstituted version.  Although I acknowledge the value for the parsed data too in most usual test cases.  Also love the checking against a schema, that's great.

Comment: I will be adding `.getTextContet()` and `.getBinaryContent()` to `body` top level node in a new release to simplify the process of similar use cases

Comment: In this first test case, the list is just one step in a peer to peer workflow.  The idea is to call each end-point in sequence.  1. List, 2. pair, 3. unpair, 4. clean (database).  The things listed are not added by a different peer process.  I'm just now working on one small chunk (a stepping stone) of the whole sequence.  It might be useful to have a sequence of calls.  The big problem there is matching outputs from one (say) GET to inputs to a subsequent POST, and so on.

Comment: @MykolaGolubyev I'm glad you added `body.getTextContent()`. I have access in the JUnit tests to the DTOs used in the Spring Boot Controllers, so for complex validations it's easier to me, or more practicable, to convert the JSON back to DTOs with the `ObjectMapper`, and use AssertJ to do typesafe assertions. E.g. `objectMapper.readValue(httpGetAsJson(PATH_COMPANIES + "/" + uuid), CompanyReadDto.class)`, where `httpGetAsJson` is kind of `String httpGetAsJson(String urlPath) { return http.get(urlPath, (header, body) -> { assertThat(body.isList()).isFalse(); return body.getTextContent(); }); }`

Comment: @t0r0X glad it worked! Any chance you can elaborate on complex validations?  One thing you lose when dealing with text is response coverage percentage and additional reporting. My preference would be to improve validation capabilities so you are not forced to convert