# How to retrieve a Long value from WebTau response body Map<String,?> representation?

Tags: java, json, long-integer, webtau

I am retrieving the JSON request body from WebTau as a Map, e.g.:

```
Map<String,?>  approvalMap = WebTauDsl.http.post(  
    callUrl,  restCallHeader, restCallBody, 
    ((header, body) -> 
    {
        return body;
    }
);
if( accessApprovalMap.get("id") instanceof Integer  )
{
    logger.info("id is Integer");
}
else if( accessApprovalMap.get("id") instanceof Long  )
{
    logger.info("id is Long");
}
```

From the logging code after the return ...

```
MonitorTest  INFO  : id is Integer
```

The question is what happens when the result is larger than MAX_INT is returned?  BIGINT isn't very common at this point, but how would 'we' know?  The string just looks like a number.

- Is there a way to override the type of a JSON field?

#### related

- [How to retrieve JSON from request body using WebTau?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72567932/how-to-retrieve-json-from-request-body-using-webtau)

Answer (score 2):

Behind the scenes [WebTau](https://github.com/testingisdocumenting/webtau) uses [com.fasterxml.jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) to parse JSON.
It automatically handles types like `Long`, `Double`, etc

Here is a [WebTau](https://github.com/testingisdocumenting/webtau) test to show numbers conversion.

Given JSON response

```json
{
  "intValue": 30000,
  "doubleValue": 100.43,
  "longValue": 9223372036854775807
}
```

```java
@Test
public void conversionOfNumbers() {
    Map<String, ?> bodyAsMap = http.get("/large-numbers", (header, body) -> {
        body.get("longValue").should(equal(9223372036854775807L));
        body.get("doubleValue").should(equal(100.43));
        body.get("intValue").should(equal(30000));

        return body;
    });

    actual(bodyAsMap.get("longValue").getClass()).should(equal(Long.class));
    actual(bodyAsMap.get("doubleValue").getClass()).should(equal(Double.class));
    actual(bodyAsMap.get("intValue").getClass()).should(equal(Integer.class));
}
```

[image: example console output]

I am thinking that your response may not have a long enough number in your test.

If you provide more info on what you plan to do with the actual numbers, I may suggest an alternative way of achieving it.

Comment: Thanks Mykola, there are many uses for `Long` values in these calls.  The main uses are Java timestamps, Long or BigInt database Id values, UUID elements.  In practice the bit pattern is what needs to be preserved.  A float will not do the job.  I suppose I can check `instanceof` against a `Long` field and convert as required.  It would be better if there's a less convoluted method.

Comment: A follow-up query.  Is it Jackson that's making the `Map<String, ?> bodyAsMap` object?  May be there's something I can use there(??).

Comment: still not clear on what is your end goal. I.e. why do you need to know the exact type Int vs Long? You won't lose data and large numbers will be converted to Long or Double based on the value.

Map<String, ?> is WebTau thing, it uses Jackson internally.

Comment: Before I knew that the `Id` data is `Integer` Java threw exceptions.  Java at least insists that I only assign a value from a Map to the _actual_ type.  `Double` is not gaurneteed to be an authentic representation of a `long`.   We want the bit patterns.

Comment: You can try to assign to a `Number` type and then request `longValue()`. Not sure I understand > we want the bit patterns. `Id` will be `Long` when the number is large enough. It is `Integer` in your case right now due to the number being small enough to fit. 
could you please tell me what are you planning to do with the `id` value later? Have a feeling there is a simpler way to achieve your final result.